# Java version 6 VM

Tags: java, jvm

I have a problem with the VM from Java.

I installed on my `PC Ubuntu 12.04` and installed the following Java version: `OpenJDK Java6 Runtime.`

I also installed the programm **DigiESP**.

> DigiESP is an ID for a DigiModul. DigiESP is based on Eclipse. Now my
>   problem when I want to start DigiESP I got a error message:

```
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0xb11c9074, pid=3216, tid=3075950272
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (11.0-b15 mixed mode, sharing linux-x86)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libxul.so+0x915074]
```

Normally I used a Windows PC, but now I need this program for a study project.
I don't know much about Ubuntu, so I could use help with this problem.

Comment: This means that something crashed in native code, in the library `libxul.so`. It's hard to say if this is because of a bug in the JVM or in a native library that DigiESP uses.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is ancient.  Java 6 is ancient (and insecure).

Comment: Looks a lot like this Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379401

Comment: @StephenC Ubuntu 12.04 may be ancient, but it is still supported for *more than a year*. This cannot be said about Java 6 though...

Answer (score 0):

From the [linked bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=379401), this may be caused by XULRunner version 2. As a workaround you may disable it, though I don't know which application components are using it.

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/dev/null
```

This system property will disable XULRunner for you.